# Speedy indexing of integer arrays in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a working production elasticsearch cluster with multiple data nodes. One of my index on this cluster has documents of following type:

```
{
 "user_id": 12131,
 "samples": [1324, 1314, 1414, 984, .....]
}
```

The constraints on this are simply that `user_id` is unique across documents and `samples` array should have unique numbers in the same document. This structure has been working fine for years. Recently it has started giving me huge indexing time. I am monitoring this indexing time via Kibana. I also noticed that CPU usage of couple of data nodes is very high. I am of the understanding that my `samples` array is searchable and not because of lot of data in it, indexing time is rocketing for those documents. I want to efficiently insert new integers in these documents. I am okay with these arrays of samples not being searchable or being tokenised.

Questions:

1. How do I identify which documents specifically are taking huge indexing time?
2. Is it possible that `samples` array has grown a lot in few documents and that is why it is taking a lot of time to add new integers into array?
3. How can I improve the indexing time?
4. I also noticed that the shard sizes are uneven. Two of the nodes with high CPU usage have 500MB of data of this index and other nodes have around 250MB. That is almost double the data on these two nodes.

The indexing time of this index is touching around 40-100s. All my other indices have been quick at indexing and they have 10x the data of this index. Please let me know if any specific metric is required. Thank you.

*Edits:*

Following is the output of `GET /_nodes/hot_threads` for one of the node with high indexing time.

```
82.9% (414.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[ip-node-ip][refresh][T#2]'
     4/10 snapshots sharing following 29 elements
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.PushPostingsWriterBase.writeTerm(PushPostingsWriterBase.java:156)
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:866)
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:344)
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.write(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:140)
       org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:109)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.flush(DefaultIndexingChain.java:173)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:444)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:539)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:653)
       org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:445)
       org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:291)
       org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:266)
       org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:256)
       org.apache.lucene.index.FilterDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(FilterDirectoryReader.java:104)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:140)
       org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:156)
       org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
       org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
       org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
       org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:883)
       org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.refresh(IndexShard.java:632)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.maybeRefreshEngine(IndexService.java:690)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.access$400(IndexService.java:92)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$AsyncRefreshTask.runInternal(IndexService.java:832)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$BaseAsyncTask.run(IndexService.java:743)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
     6/10 snapshots sharing following 26 elements
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.write(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:140)
       org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:109)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.flush(DefaultIndexingChain.java:173)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:444)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:539)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:653)
       org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:445)
       org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:291)
       org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:266)
       org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:256)
       org.apache.lucene.index.FilterDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(FilterDirectoryReader.java:104)
       org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:140)
       org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:156)
       org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
       org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
       org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
       org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:883)
       org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.refresh(IndexShard.java:632)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.maybeRefreshEngine(IndexService.java:690)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.access$400(IndexService.java:92)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$AsyncRefreshTask.runInternal(IndexService.java:832)
       org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService$BaseAsyncTask.run(IndexService.java:743)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Could you please post data from [hot-threads](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html) API for high CPU nodes? Also if you **do not** need to search by `samples` you can just set `"index": false` in the [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/mapping-index.html).

Comment: @ilvar Hi, I have added the response of hot_threads of one of the node. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's definitely terms processing on write. Try marking that field as non-indexed (you'll have to recreate the index though).

Comment: Can you tell me which of these class signify this write processing? I would like to focus of specific classes and their operations if recreation of index isn't feasible for us. Thanks.

Comment: All CPU is consumed by `org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter` which seems to be writing terms. You can use [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) if there is no copy of data outside Elasticsearch.

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot. I'll let you about this in a day and if whether it leads to resolution.

Comment: @ilvar The issue we had was one of the documents had 500K+ elements in `samples` array. Any operation on this document is causing this CPU spike.

Comment: Is this slowness still the same if you mark the `samples` field as non-indexed? Or you just removed that document altogether?